# How to change default launchers in the unity dashboard?

Tags: 11.10, unity

how can I change the default applications showed when I open unity.
At the moment it's Chromium, OpenShot, Thunderbird and Banshee. I'd like to replace the Banshee starter with a customized icon and command.
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a customized command & icon you'd need to create a custom .desktop & preferably place in a typical applications dir. like ~/.local/share/applications ; /usr/local/share/applications ; /usr/share/applications, (i'd use the 1st one

The Exec= line for your command, the Icon= line for the icon

You could try including in the .desktop a line like this, may help your .desktop show up in System Settings > System Info > Default applicatons > Music

```
MimeType=audio/x-vorbis+ogg;
```

If it doesn't, no matter. Open ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list & in the [Default Applications] section create or edit this line, using the name of your custom.desktop

```
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=customname.deskktop
```

Comment: oh no, it doesnt!
the command is "/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=http://grooveshark.com/" but using the launcher just opens chromium normally with my homepage!

Comment: Then you need to edit your Exec= command to do what you want or if need be use a script as the Exec=. If you just wanted it to open on that page it would be this. - Exec=chromium-browser  grooveshark.com

Comment: This does the same thing as my method but not in a GUI, depends what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Open the terminal and install gnome panel:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Then you can run the item editor:

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/banshee.desktop
```

[image: Banshee Properties]

I can't check if this is exactly the right command because I've lost my password but it should work.

Comment: doesn't work me. appreciate your effort anyway - thank you!